# Korven the Prime as a Pet

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Recently I have been trying to level up gathering professions on one of my characters in order to obtain the [Working Better as a Team](http://www.wowhead.com/achievement=6626/working-better-as-a-team) guild achievement, my herbalism skill was at 579 so I decided to go to the dread wastes, in the hope that I would find herbs of a sufficient quality to level my herb gathering skill. Whilst doing so I decided to do a few quests as a means of keeping things interesting.

After completing the The Scale-Lord quest I was able to strike the amber that held Korven the prime and release him from his slumber. When he awoke I decided that I didn't want to get tangled up doing loads of quests that I had done before, so I didn't click on him to begin any of the quests that he offers, and instead left the underground dwelling of the scale lord to make my way elsewhere.

At this point I noticed that Korven was following me, and soon after leaving the underground dwelling I found myself engaged in combat with several [Mistblade rippers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmhXn.jpg), much to my surprise and delight, Korven took part in the battle, though he didn't seem to be doing much damage.

Anyway, my question is this:

**How can I keep Korven the prime as my pet?** I imagine that he will continue to follow me as long as I don't take any of his quests and/or complete them. If I leave the dread wastes will I lost him? I'm reluctant to try it just in case I leave and find that he no longer follows me around when I get back.

Here is a picture of Korven the Prime

[image: Korven the prime as my pet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

This is a phased npc follower.  You will have this follower in certain areas as long as you meet the quest criteria.  You may leave and return - the follower will vanish when you leave the relevant areas and the follower will return when you return.

Comment: Korven the prime vanishes when you move a certain distance away from the lake of stars.